# Mongoose saving Scheme with Pre Hook not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new to Nodejs and Mongoose, things were working fine until the new release of mongoose where promises are depreciated. I see it is recommended to use bluebird which I am trying to do. I have the following code:

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
var user = new User(body);
user.save().then(() => {
    return user.generateAuthToken();
}).then((token) => {
    res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
}).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
})
```

});

and the pre hook:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
var user = this;
if (user.isModified('password')) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
} else {
    next();
}
```

});

after creating the hash and calling `next()` nothing happens why is this happening? 
All help would be appreciated

EDIT:
The call never goes into the `generateAuthToken()` function

Comment: My pre hooks are also not working. I have Mongoose 4.13.6. I doesn't matter if I use Bluebird or native Promises. Tried "save", "update", "findOneAndUpdate" hooks....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

Comment: I have tried that where i connect to my DB and it still doesn't work.
Things work until i call next() after the creation of hash and nothing happens

Comment: you need to write this in userModel.js file

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that my importing of the mongoose variable was incorrect and i have solved the issue by fixing that.